# AH01797: client denied by server configuration (any destination)

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, squirrelmail

I'm getting the error as per title whereever I try to access by using my public IP address of my VPS. It's not something related only to virtual hostes, as I saw in others threads, but in general if I try to access to phpmyadmim, squirrelmail or whatever, I get this error.

Below the error.log details:

```
[Thu Jun 04 14:49:27.260966 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 6190] [client 151.77.210.5:56615] 
*AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Thu Jun 04 14:49:27.329891 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 6191] [client 151.77.210.5:56616] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Thu Jun 04 14:49:31.763486 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 6190] [client 151.77.210.5:56615] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
[Thu Jun 04 14:49:39.399712 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 6192] [client 151.77.210.5:56618] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/squirrelmail/*
```

This is my apache2.conf:

```
    DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    Timeout 300

    KeepAlive On

    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    HostnameLookups Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    Include ports.conf

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    AccessFileName .htaccess

    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>

    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf*
```

I appreciate in advance any help may you give me!
Thank you